# Start with ZendFramework 1 or 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I developed in PHP for a long time without a framework, I just use PDO for help me with connection database. But now I decided to learn about Zend Framework to increase my productivity, to avoid repetitious code.

I work with Java WEB too, (Hibernate/JPA + JSF + Spring + Maven) that make my work more easy and organized, and I would like to bring it to PHP too.

So my big doubt is: I should starting with ZendFramework 1 or ZendFramework 2? I saw a lot of companies requiring knowledge about ZendFramework 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend Framework 1 is a dying product. It is the older Version of the Framework and Version 2 has already being developed with Version 3 being on it's way for later 2014 / early 2015 approximately. The reason for companies still requiring ZF1 knowledge is due to their old codebase.

Many companies are starting to re-write their products using newer frameworks to gain the advantages of the newer ones.

With this in mind: clearly go for ZF2 (or any other new fully OOP/MVC Framework). Once you master it, you'll be able to read ZF1 code just as well and you can easily adapt into any other Framework that your company may require.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I imagine that you use ZendFramwork 2